# sql server order by TOP 100 PERCENT in SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my query:

```
select * from   
(select name,empID,salary,[deducted salary] = salary-7000 from tblEmpDetails   
order by Joined_Date) TmpTbl where [decucted salary] > 50000
```

It was giving error:

```
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables,   
subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
```

Then I changed my query to:

```
select * from   
(select TOP 100 PERCENT name,empID,salary,[deducted salary] = salary-7000   
from tblEmpDetails order by Joined_Date) TmpTbl where [decucted salary] > 50000
```

Now its is working fine.
My query is using TOP 100 is the correct method or any other work around is there for this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Sorting in subquery is normally not allowed because it is meaningless -- top level query is not guaranteed to preserve the order. Can you move `order by` to the outer query instead?

Comment: then i have to include Joined_Date in the inner select query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have wanted the ORDER BY in the outer query, e.g.

```
select name,empID,salary,[deducted salary] from   
(select name,empID,salary,[deducted salary] = salary-7000, Joined_Date
   from tblEmpDetails   
) TmpTbl where [decucted salary] > 50000
order by Joined_Date
```

**EDIT** - Yes you need to include Joined_Date in the inner query to sort by it on the outer query, as well as explicitly listing only the 4 columns desired instead of `*`.

But you could also have written the query in one level

```
  select name,empID,salary,[deducted salary] = salary-7000
    from tblEmpDetails
   where salary-7000 > 50000
order by Joined_Date
```

Note that `salary-7000` although repeated in the query is only *evaluated* once by SQL Server because it is smart enough to use it twice.

Comment: i think OP want to know why the it doesn't give error when we use order by with top in subquery,i m not to sure what OP want but i want to know why first query give error and second not?

Comment: Nice bit of explanation concerning `salary-7000`!

Comment: @Amit The question was `is using TOP 100 is the correct method or any other work around is there for this` and the answer is *there is probably a better query*, as shown.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi i m not saying at all there is any problem in query,obiviously it is best one for the purpose, i write above also that i dont know what OP want or questined i personally want to know why order by work with top..i m asking to clear my concept only i m not questioning on your query??

Comment: ORDER BY is valid in subquery with TOP because you may want to look at several or more commonly just one row based on a specific order, e.g. `select u.name, (select top 1 Log.IPAddress from Log where Log.UserID=u.UserID order by Log.time desc) LastKnownIP from users u`. It works with TOP to achieve something meaningful. ORDER BY without TOP however does not achieve anything since the presentation order is not controlled by the subquery, only ever at the outermost query. Making it invalid syntax helps make it clearer.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi very clear ...thanks for the explanation its bothering me a lot..+1 for for such a wonderfull explanation...thanks a lot mr. RichardTheKiwi..